# Logarithmic function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$

Tags: functions

Total math noob here so sorry if my question sounds stupid or trivial.

I'm looking for a function $f$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ that kinda behaves like $\ln(x)$, that is to say that $f(x)$ grows fairly rapidly to $1$ then caps.

It needs to be defined for (at least) $x \in [0, 1]$.

Sorry again for the terminology errors, I'm french and not so familiar with the English terms, plus schools is years behind me.

Comment: Could you sketch $f$?

Comment: Something like this: https://ibb.co/JyRDhr3

Comment: (I don't really care about the exact values I just want it to grow fast to 1).

Comment: What do you think about the tanh function? Or the sigmoid function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}$? They do not satisfy the conditions exactly, but you can transform them.

Comment: $\log_2(x+1)$ seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Can you help me write it on https://www.desmos.com/calculator? I can't seem to write log2 the correct way.

Comment: But yeah log2(0) = 0 and log2(1) = 1 that's good, I just wanna see how the intermediate values look like.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \exp(0.01x) - \exp(-5x)$? It fits your requirements pretty well in the $[0, 1]$ range. See [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ofzdzjijh9).

Comment: @DougM mmmh I managed to display the graph, to me the value doesn't grow quick enough.

Comment: @an4s Oh yes really good!

Comment: Just a part of a circle? $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ i.e. $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop awesome!

Comment: ?! I thought you needed a logarithm involved somewhere, so my circle was really a shot in the dark... Glad it helped!

Comment: I just need f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1 and "growing fast" in between. Since I'm a stranger to the world of maths, the only thing I could think about that had the "shape" I want was ln(x). Tbh I'm kinda surprised there isn't a... "named" function that does what I want (I mean like ln(x) or sin(x) or e(x), something like that). I would have thought there would considering my conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,t)=x^t=e^{t\ln x}$ for some $t\in\Bbb R$. Then trivially $f(0,t)=0, f(1,t)=1$ is fixed.

We have that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=tx^{t-1}; t>0,x\geq0\implies\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\geq0$$
that is, the function is always increasing across $x\in [0,1]$ as long as $t>0$.

Moreover, $$\epsilon >0 \implies f(x, t+\epsilon)=x^{t+\epsilon}=x^tx^\epsilon>x^t=f(x,t)$$that is, picking a bigger $t$ gives a smaller result at each point.

Thusly, we pick $f(x)=x^t$ with $t$ being infinitesimal.

[Here are a few to see it work](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n0c7rlbkrp)

Comment: Simple, efficient, elegant !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain what particular characteristics you're after, but ln(x+1)/ln(2) certainly has log-like behavior, though I can't really say it "caps." Sqrt(x * (2 - x)) has a derivative that goes to infinity at 0 and zero at 1, which is about as "grow rapidly to 1 then cap" as you could get. (On [0, 1] it's a quarter of a circle, centered at (1, 0)).

EDIT: I should have read the above comments; I'd have seen the circle idea was already mentioned. I obviously need to look into the distinction between "comments" and "answers."

EDIT 2: Though the circle seemed to work for you (which is a named function: a circle!), another one I should have thought of is ln(k*x+1)/ln(k+1). The larger the *k*, the faster it initially increases.